# apache RewriteCond variable for parts of REQUEST_URI

Tags: apache-http-server, drupal, rewrite

I migrate a static html site to drupal CMS, most content I just copied the html for now and want to leave it as is and make the relative links to pdf files working. Drupal has all files in this dir: ( I copied the whole tree of FORMER SUB DIRS - nice, want to keep that )

```
 DOCROOT/sites/mydomain.xyz/files/FORMER/SUB/DIRS/filename.pdf
```

So all relative links in the CMS contents become now:

```
 http://mydomain.xyz/node/FORMER/SUB/DIRS/filename.pdf
```

I want to check if the file exists and then rewrite the url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond     /var/www/mydomain.xyz/sites/mydomain.xyz/files/%{REQUEST_URI MINUS "node/"} -f
RewriteRule     (.*)$ /sites/mydomain.xyz/files/$1  [R]
```

How could i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need `RewriteCond` backreferences. Please see [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for details.

Roughly (but I have no way of testing it at the moment):

```
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI MINUS} ^/node(.*)
RewriteCond     /var/www/mydomain.xyz/sites/mydomain.xyz/files/%1 -f
...
```

The `%1` is a `RewriteCond` backreference, as opposed to a `RewriteRule` backreference (which would be `$1`)

Answer (score 0):

works that way

```
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} ^/node(.*)
RewriteCond     /var/www/schottdorf.de/sites/schottdorf.de/files%1 -f
RewriteRule     .* /sites/schottdorf.de/files/%1  [L]
```

(but unfortunately i forgot that there is another level of subdirs directly under docroot which apache cannot know.)

I want to figure out if I set drupal path alias for all the top level documents - I'll see

Comment: You can edit your original question. Anyway, if you need some conditionals, you may want to use [E:VARNAME:value] in your rules so as to set variables depending on certain conditions and then consume them inside other rules (or generally elsewhere) ...